# Python Not Writing To Last File?

Tags: python, function, glob

I made a function that takes in a filename, what to write and a location out of fun and so I could make my code look cleaner. But my issue is it will not write to the last file. I can remove path6 and it will not write to path5 if it's the final one so that tells me I've got a bug but I cannot figure it out. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks here my code

```
import os
import glob

"""
Function takes in filename, userInput and folder location
then write to the selected file. Also changes directory to mainDir
"""
def writeto(filewrite, userInput, location):
    filewrite = open("_Script.bat", "w",)
    filewrite.write(userInput)
    print("Writing settings to file: " + location + fileName)
    filewrite.close()
    os.chdir(mainDir)
    os.chdir(location)

print("\nCurrent Directory is : " + os.getcwd())

fileName = "__Script.bat"
path = 'C:/Users/Admin/MyDocs/Logs and Sheets 1'
path2 = 'C:/Users/Admin/MyDocs/Logs and Sheets 2'
path3 = 'C:/Users/Admin/MyDocs/Logs and Sheets 3'
path4 = 'C:/Users/Admin/MyDocs/Logs and Sheets 4'
path5 = 'C:/Users/Admin/MyDocs/Logs and Sheets 5'
path6 = 'C:/Users/Admin/MyDocs/Logs and Sheets 6'
mainDir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path)

settingsinput = input("\nPlease enter your input: ")


writeto(fileName, userInput, path)
writeto(fileName, userInput, path2)
writeto(fileName, userInput, path3)
writeto(fileName, userInput, path4)
writeto(fileName, userInput, path5)
writeto(fileName, userInput, path6)
```

Comment: You are changing to the directory *after* opening and writing the file - so the first file goes in some unknown directory, and the last directory never gets a file written to it.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was going to be something simple. I thought about the directory changing but couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need to change directories here at all. You can do `open(location + "/_Script.bat", "w")`.

Comment: Try to add filewrite.flush() before filewrite.close().

Comment: @Bohdan Why?  close() does a flush.

Comment: Thank you, it would write to the first file I'm trying to understand why should it go in some unknown directory? I'm confused because it was only not writing to the last directory. Just trying to understand it a bit deeperxD

Comment: Generally, i'm trying to understand what  your function writeto does: it takes 3 args, the 1st one shuld be a filename but in fact file name is constant in open("__Script.bat", ..) method.

Comment: It lets me write into multiple script files, it's not really practical but let's me write into scripts I have. I'm trying to get the filename to be passed into as a argument via string and not hard code it but not quite there yet